# Не приходят данные с формы , ошибка Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: php, ajax, reactjs, axios

Изначально была ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я ее исправил сначала добавив в Acess-Control....:'*' , отправил данные с формы но ,что в $_REQUEST , что в $_POST пусто. Дальше я попробовал сменить header на  Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization , все тоже самое ошибки нет, но $_POST $_REQUEST снова пустые. Как мне решить эту проблему?
Вот сам обработчик:

```
<?

header('Content-type: json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");


$theme = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["THEME"]));
$tel = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["TEL"]));
$email = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["EMAIL"]));
$msg = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["MESSAGE"]));
if ($_REQUEST["THEME"] == 'Не выбрано' || $_REQUEST["TEL"] == '' || $_REQUEST["EMAIL"] == '') {

    echo json_encode(
        array(
            "STATUS" => 'ERROR!',
            "REQ" => $_REQUEST
        )
    );
    die();


} else {

    $to = 'guscha.e@yandex.ru';
    $sub = 'Вопрос юристу';
    $fields = array($theme, $email, $msg);
    mail($to, $sub, 'Нужна помощь', $fields);
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            "THEME" => $theme,
            "TEL" => $tel,
            "EMAIL" => $email,
            "MESSAGE" => $msg,
            "STATUS" => 'OK',
            "REQ" => $_REQUEST


        )
    );
    die();


}
```

Вот ajax:

```
 ajaxFunc() {

    let form = document.querySelector('#order-jurist');
    let data = serialize(form, {hash: true});
    axios({

        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://военгарант.рф/api/jurist-order.php',
        data: data,

    })
        .then(res => {


            // console.log('ok');
            console.log(res);
            // console.log(item);


        })
        .catch(function (er) {

            console.log('error');
            console.log(er);
        });
    console.log(data);

}
```

Вот ответ от сервера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

file_get_contents("php://input"):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что [находится](http://php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php) в `file_get_contents("php://input")`?

Comment: Дайте данные до отправки

Comment: @StackOverflow, добавил

Comment: Помогло ответ для решения вашей проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

`axios` отправляет данные с заголовком `header('Content-Type: application/json')`, потому и данные не попадали в массив `$_POST`.

Есть два решения для `POST` запроса с помощью  `axios`.
Что бы отправлять на сервер данные нужного формата и с нужными заголовками.

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone'
    }
})
.then(function(response) {

    console.log(response);

})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

> Надо явно задать параметр `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }`.

А это второй способ с применением [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('firstName', 'Fred');
params.append('lastName', 'Flintstone');
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {params}
})
.then(function(response) {

    console.log(response);

})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

А здесь с помощью `URLSearchParams` создаем объект данных что бы отправить их в формате `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` а не `JSON`․

> Примечание: `URLSearchParams` не поддерживается всеми браузерами. Поддержку броузеров `URLSearchParams` можете смотреть [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Comment: Я зада параметр явно и вот что получилось, смотрите последний скрин

Comment: @Ristek  Это уже не по части фронта. вы что используете в `back`? какой то фреймворк? Что бы точно понять что это не из за `ajax`, Просто передайте запрос на пустой `php` файл, и там посмотрите нормально ли все, и обратно дайте ответ на фронт из этого файла.

Comment: нет, никакой фреймворк не использую, я пробовал на другие обработчики запрос посылать , но и реквест и пост пустые

Comment: @Ristek без этого хедера они будут пустыми, не возможно без этого сделать пост запрос.

Comment: ну вот на скринах я все представлено

Comment: @Ristek Там видно `xsrf` ошибку, а это совсем другое.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71042/discussion-between-ristek-and-stack-overflow).